# C# How to make an object from class Person kill another?

Tags: c#, oop, object

In the following code, I'm trying to learn how to get objects to interact with each other, because I feel that's a bit more important than what I have done now which is simply collect a bunch of variables assign to each object.

For fun, what I want these different objects to do is to kill each other. The person named Jack can kill. The other two can not. What I want Jack to do is strike the other two, making them lose 1, 5 or 10 HitPoints multiple times until they are dead, and then set their Alive to false.

I don't know how to even start this, but I think it would be a very fun and interesting exercise.

The most important thing about doing this is learning how one object can directly change something about a different object, just because it can, and that the objects it has then changed, will then suffer a consequence from this action.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OOP_Learning
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person p1; 
            p1 = new Person("Jack", 27, true, true, 10);

            Person p2;
            p2 = new Person("Vincent", 63, true, false, 10);

            Person p3;
            p3 = new Person("Tim", 13, true, false, 10);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }    
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public bool Alive { get; set; }
        public bool AbilityToKill { get; set; }
        public int HitPoints { get; set; }
        public Person(string name, int age, bool alive, bool abilityToKill, int hitPoints)
        {
            HitPoints = hitPoints;
            AbilityToKill = abilityToKill;
            Alive = alive;
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some parts of your question have simple answers. For example, p2.HitPoints -= 10 will take away hit points. And p3.Alive = false will kill someone off. But you could make it more complex, like Alive could be a calculated field: get { return this.HitPoints > 0; }. Stuff like that. Or you could have a TakeHit method, which reduces the hit count by the given number, or even calculates a random number. Dream big

Comment: Also, I'd recommend you change the title of this question, because "kill" might be misinterpreted as terminating a process, which is also possible. You just want to make changes to your objects

Comment: @baileyrt These are excellent points. I do like to dream big and get this close knitted and sophisticated with time, but I'd also like to start small to get a better fundamental understanding. I believe the first thing I have to do is learn about the this keyword. 

I edited the question a bit too so I think it will be easier to understand now

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you mean?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }    
    public int Age { get; private set; }
    public bool Alive { get; private set; }
    public bool AbilityToKill { get; private set; }
    public int HitPoints { get; private set; }

    public void Hit(int points)
    {
        this.HitPoints -= points;
        if (this.HitPoints <= 0)
        {
            this.HitPoints = 0;
            this.Alive = false;
        }
    }

    public Person(string name, int age, bool alive, bool abilityToKill, int hitPoints)
    {
        this.HitPoints = hitPoints;
        this.AbilityToKill = abilityToKill;
        this.Alive = alive;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}
```

---

Now with the check for `AbilityToKill`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
    public bool Alive { get; private set; }
    public bool AbilityToKill { get; private set; }
    public int HitPoints { get; private set; }

    public int Attack(Person victim, int points)
    {
        var hp = victim.HitPoints;
        if (this.AbilityToKill)
        {
            victim.HitPoints -= points;
            if (victim.HitPoints <= 0)
            {
                victim.HitPoints = 0;
                victim.Alive = false;
            }
        }
        hp -= victim.HitPoints;
        return hp;
    }

    public Person(string name, int age, bool alive, bool abilityToKill, int hitPoints)
    {
        this.HitPoints = hitPoints;
        this.AbilityToKill = abilityToKill;
        this.Alive = alive;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
var jack = new Person("Jack", 27, true, true, 10);
var vincent = new Person("Vincent", 63, true, false, 10);
var tim = new Person("Tim", 13, true, false, 10);

var damage_done = jack.Attack(vincent, 20);
Console.WriteLine(damage_done);
```

The `Attack` method returns the actual number of hits points reduced by the attack - the damage dealt.

---

And here's a more strongly-typed version. Using `bool` for properties isn't always the clearest way to code. Through in some enums and it's clearer.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
    public Alive Alive { get; private set; }
    public AbilityToKill AbilityToKill { get; private set; }
    public int HitPoints { get; private set; }

    public int Attack(Person victim, int points)
    {
        var hp = victim.HitPoints;
        if (this.AbilityToKill == AbilityToKill.Yes)
        {
            victim.HitPoints -= points;
            if (victim.HitPoints <= 0)
            {
                victim.HitPoints = 0;
                victim.Alive = Alive.No;
            }
        }
        hp -= victim.HitPoints;
        return hp;
    }

    public Person(string name, int age, Alive alive, AbilityToKill abilityToKill, int hitPoints)
    {
        this.HitPoints = hitPoints;
        this.AbilityToKill = abilityToKill;
        this.Alive = alive;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}

public enum Alive { Yes, No }
public enum AbilityToKill { Yes, No }
```

It's used like this:

```
var jack = new Person("Jack", 27, Alive.Yes, AbilityToKill.Yes, 10);
var vincent = new Person("Vincent", 63, Alive.Yes, AbilityToKill.No, 10);
var tim = new Person("Tim", 13, Alive.Yes, AbilityToKill.No, 10);

var damage_done = jack.Attack(vincent, 20);
Console.WriteLine(damage_done);
```

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - I specifically went with a simple approach as the OP doesn't appear to have a lot of experience.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - Please don't delete your comments. It makes understanding the conversation much harder.

Comment: As my comment related to state that no longer exists, I do not find cleaning up as a bad thing.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - But it does relate directly to my comment. So now my comment has no context. I do find that "cleaning up", as you call it, creates a big mess.

Comment: There was no added value for the reader in this conversation anyway, I see no point to treat the page as write only in such case. Now that changed, now we are talking about deleting posts that bring nothing to the reader. It is totally offtopic, but ok, it has some point, in that case I agree deleting comments can cause problems.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hey man. Thank you very much for this step by step instruction, I understand almost everything. What I don't understand is why we put "Person victim" as a parameter there. I don't see how a variable will be sent to the Hit method to be used inside the Hit method. Is it possible to explain how this comes together without using too many big words? thank you.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hey, I've played around a bit. Is: 
    p1.Hit(p2, 50);
correct as an example? That the parameter is actually an object?

Comment: @Enigmativity My mind is blowing when piecing this stuff together, mate. Thank you!

Comment: @Furnus - The updated code that passes `Person victim` also changed the name of the method from `Hit` to `Attack`. It did that because the semantic changed. The `Hit` method didn't care who did the attacking so it didn't need the `Person` parameter, but in order to check the `AbilityToKill` property we need to have a reference to the person who is attacking and a reference to the victim to deduct the hit points.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 methods in the `Person` class.

1. `Hit` -> This method reduce the `HitPoints` on self object with each hit. When the `HitPoints` become Zero, status `Alive` is set to `false`.
2. Kill -> This will take person as a parameter and call `Hit` method on that person till that person is `Alive`.

**Add following methods to `Person` class:**

```
    public void Hit()
    {
        if(Alive)
        {
            if(HitPoints > 0)
            {
                HitPoints -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Alive = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Kill(Person person)
    {
        if(!AbilityToKill)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You don't have ability to kill! You cannont kill {0}.", person.Name);
            return false;
        }

        while(person.Alive)
        {
            person.Hit();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0} is dead.", person.Name);

        return true;
    }
```

**Call `Kill` method in `Main` method.**

```
    p2.Kill(p3);
    p1.Kill(p2);
    p1.Kill(p3);
```

Hope this helps!